# Console closing after i give a first value to my bidimensional vector

Tags: c++, function, vector

I created bidimensional vector function, that was supposed to fill a vector a return to my main function, but after i try insert the first value the console stops getting new values and just ends.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
std::vector <std::vector <int>> fill(int lin, int col) {
    int val;
    std::vector <std::vector<int>> mat;

    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            std::cin >> val;
            mat[i][j] = val;
        }
    }

    return mat;
}

void size(int &lin, int &col) {
    std::cout << "Quantidade de linhas: ";
    std::cin >> lin;
    std::cout << "Quantidade de colunas: ";
    std::cin >> col;
}

int main() {
    int opc, lin, col;
    std::vector <std::vector<int>> matA;
    std::vector <std::vector<int>> matB;

    std::cout << "1. Soma\n2. Subtracao\n3. Multiplicacao\n4. Divisao\n >";
    std::cin >> opc;


    switch (opc) {
        case 1:
            //soma
            size(lin, col);
            matA = fill(lin, col);
            matB = fill(lin, col);      
    }
}
```

Comment: `mat[i][j] = val;` this doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: I believe you need to `resize` your vectors based on `lin` and `col`. In its current state, the vector size is `(0,0)`.

Comment: Use `at()` instead of `operator[]` for element access and it'll be obvious.

Comment: Why use `vector` of `vector`s, instead of `boost::matrix`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resize the vector (actually you need to resize both external and every internal vector). See the changes in lines 3 and 6:

```
std::vector <std::vector <int>> fill(int lin, int col) {
    int val;
    std::vector <std::vector<int>> mat(lin);

    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
        mat[i].resize(col);
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            std::cin >> val;
            mat[i][j] = val;
        }
    }

    return mat;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfect. Just to clarify: I need to declare the initial vector size in mat(lin), creating the rows, and in mat[i].resize(col) i create the columns for each row.

Comment: @LcsxX `mat(lin)` allows you to allocate `lin` elements in the constructor.